# Changing order of trim specifications for graphicx package

Tags: graphics

I am using `graphicx` package to get figure for my document from a pdf file.

Here is the code I am using.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
%left bottom right top
\includegraphics[page=101,clip,trim=97mm 189mm 43mm 48mm]{book.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I want to use the parameters in this order: *top*, *bottom*, *left* and *right*.
I have many figures to arrange and
I am using *Acrobat Reader* to determine the crop box of the graphics.
It will be much more easier for to see the values at first glance.

Comment: the default order is consistent with specification of bounding box and viewport keys where you specify the coordinates of the bottom left and top right corner of the rectangle. If you want a different order I would add a new key rather than redefine an existing one, in case you ever need the document to be portable and combined with other graphics inclusions using the standard order.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your example, you'll be able to see the location of `graphicx.sty`. On my machine, it is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
```

This allowed me to examine the code, and look at the following

```
 \def\Gread@parse@vp#1 #2 #3 #4 #5\\{%
   \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vllx{#1}%
   \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vlly{#2}%
   \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vurx{#3}%
   \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vury{#4}}%
```

So, for your purposes, we need to change the ordering of `#1`,..., `#4`.

A complete MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
% original: left bottom right top
% \def\Gread@parse@vp#1 #2 #3 #4 #5\\{%
%   \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vllx{#1}%
%   \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vlly{#2}%
%   \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vurx{#3}%
%   \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vury{#4}}%
% NEW: top, bottom, left and right
\def\Gread@parse@vp#1 #2 #3 #4 #5\\{%
\Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vllx{#4}%
\Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vlly{#2}%
\Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vurx{#1}%
\Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vury{#3}}%
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[
    % NEW: top, bottom, left and right
    clip,trim=5mm 10mm 15mm 20mm]%
{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do I need to use `\makeatother` after `\Gin@defaultbp\Gin@vury{#3}}%`?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it'll depend what you want to do in the rest of your preamble